# "Create kernel failed" in Tensorflow when mapping nodes to different devices

Tags: tensorflow

I have done some manual graph partitioning in tensorFlow using a simple hash function to map the nodes on different (2) CPU devices.
When I map the whole graph on the first device or the second it works. (That is why I don't understand the error message "Create kernel failed").
Do you have any idea what is wrong?

However the following error occurs:

`E tensorflow/core/framework/op_segment.cc:53] Create kernel failed:       Invalid argument: AttrValue must not have reference type value of   float_ref
    for attr 'tensor_type'
    ; NodeDef: Variable/_9 = _Recv[_start_time=0, client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:1", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_10_Variable", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT_REF, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](^zeros/_11); Op<name=_Recv; signature= -> tensor:tensor_type; attr=tensor_type:type; attr=tensor_name:string; attr=send_device:string; attr=send_device_incarnation:int; attr=recv_device:string; attr=client_terminated:bool,default=false; is_stateful=true>
E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:334] Executor failed to create kernel. Invalid argument: AttrValue must not have reference type value of float_ref
     for attr 'tensor_type'
    ; NodeDef: Variable/_9 = _Recv[_start_time=0, client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:1", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_10_Variable", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT_REF, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](^zeros/_11); Op<name=_Recv; signature= -> tensor:tensor_type; attr=tensor_type:type; attr=tensor_name:string; attr=send_device:string; attr=send_device_incarnation:int; attr=recv_device:string; attr=client_terminated:bool,default=false; is_stateful=true>
     [[Node: Variable/_9 = _Recv[_start_time=0, client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:1", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_10_Variable", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT_REF, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](^zeros/_11)]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/larissa/Desktop/GraphPartSched/Theorie/TensorFlow/TensorFlow_Tutorials/MNIST_For_ML_Beginners.py", line 53, in <module>
    sess.run(init)
  File "/Users/larissa/tensorflowSource/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 717, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Users/larissa/tensorflowSource/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 915, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/Users/larissa/tensorflowSource/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 965, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/Users/larissa/tensorflowSource/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 985, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: AttrValue must not have reference type value of float_ref
     for attr 'tensor_type'
    ; NodeDef: Variable/_9 = _Recv[_start_time=0, client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:1", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_10_Variable", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT_REF, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](^zeros/_11); Op<name=_Recv; signature= -> tensor:tensor_type; attr=tensor_type:type; attr=tensor_name:string; attr=send_device:string; attr=send_device_incarnation:int; attr=recv_device:string; attr=client_terminated:bool,default=false; is_stateful=true>
     [[Node: Variable/_9 = _Recv[_start_time=0, client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:1", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_10_Variable", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT_REF, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](^zeros/_11)]]`

Comment: can you post reproducible example?

Comment: I uploaded the code on GitHub: https://github.com/larissa95/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/costum_placer.cc#L102
I replaced the simple_placer with a hash placement (to test some basic modification). When I run tensorFlow with the simple MINST example from the TensorFlow website, the error message occurs.

Comment: Some ops have colocation constraints, for instance in default placement op for "var/read" node is placed on the same device as "var" node, I'm wondering if your problem is because those constraints are broken

Comment: I suspect `Assign` only works if it's on the same device as the variable it's assigning to. Print the `tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()` and look for `s: "loc:@param"` lines, those specify colocation constraints, and check if your placement doesn't satisfy those constraints.